# iframe an external page div without using jQuery

Tags: javascript

How to show in an iframe a specific external page div without using jQuery or other external js libraries?

I know there is JQuery can solve this but i can't use it.

Thanks!

EDIT: I just want to show the content of the div, not what is outside of it

Thanks again!

Comment: Just the `<div>`? What about any styling information that might be linked to in the header, or any Javascript linked to at the bottom of the page that's required for page layout? Whether you load it yourself, or get jQuery to do it, without the other stuff it's not likely to be very pretty.

Answer (score 1):

You can just set the iframe's src property to the url of a page and use # anchor to position to your div

Answer (score 0):

Using an `iframe` never required jQuery to start with:

```
<iframe width="400" height="300" src="http://example.com/"></iframe>
```

Note that some sites use the [X-Frame-Options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/X-Frame-Options) header, or Javascript running within the frame, to prevent themselves from being framed. There is no way to override this.